"Degenerate" Schur polynomials
Let's say that a Schur polynomial is degenerate if its number of variables is less than the weight of the partition it is associated to. For example, according to Sage, the Schur polynomial of the integer partition $(2,2)$ in three variables is x0^2*x1^2 + x0^2*x1*x2 + x0*x1^2*x2 + x0^2*x2^2 + x0*x1*x2^2 + x1^2*x2^2:
Sym = SymmetricFunctions(QQ)
s = Sym.schur()
s22 = s[2, 2]
s22_with_3_variables = s22.expand(3)
# x0^2*x1^2 + x0^2*x1*x2 + x0*x1^2*x2 + x0^2*x2^2 + x0*x1*x2^2 + x1^2*x2^2

I'm wondering whether such polynomials can really be considered as Schur polynomials? For example, it is well known that the Hall norm (norm associated to the Hall inner product) of a Schur polynomial is $1$, but this is not true for such a "degenerate" Schur polynomial:
poly = Sym.from_polynomial(s22_with_3_variables)
poly.scalar(poly)
# 5

So what is the point here? Are such polynomials not considered as Schur polynomials, or is there something which makes no sense in the problem I just described?

If we write $s_{\lambda} = \sum K_{\lambda,\mu} m_{\mu}$ then for a number of variables at least $|\lambda|$ this formula describes the decomposition of a Schur polynomial into monomial symmetric polynomials, as well as the decomposition of the Schur function into monomial symmetric functions, but when the number of variables is too small some of the monomial symmetric polynomials become zero and the equation "degenerates." You should read a standard source on symmetric functions, like Macdonald or Stanley.

One should think of Schur functions in $n$ variables as specializations of "ordinary" Schur functions (assumed to be in infinitely many variables). See EC2, Prop. 7.8.2.
